# XAML - Multiple Columns for a 1 dimensional collection

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, collections

I'm trying to create a grid that will take in a one dimensional collection (in my testing i'm using a string array, but this could be expanded to custom objects), and then display them this way:

```
Item1        Item2
Item3        Item4
Item5
```

I understand how to do this explicitly using Row/Col definitions, however I want to be able to create a XAML snippet that I can say, "Here is a collection of items, I want X number of columns", and it will create that structure. It seems like such a simple thing but I cannot seem to figure it out. Is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: Don’t use a grid, use an items control with a panel that aligns the elements like that. (why would you even use a grid for that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `WrapPanel`, but some trickery will need to be involved so that there's always 2 columns.

See below:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel ItemWidth="200" 
                       MaxWidth="400"
                       MinWidth="400"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Code-behind (for demo):

```
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new Data
        {
            Items = new List<string>
            {
                "item 1",
                 "item 2",
                  "item 3",
                   "item 4",
                    "item 5",
                     "item 6",
                      "item 7",
            }
        };
    }
}

public class Data
{
    public List<string> Items { get; set; } 
}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware that control existed. Guess I'll hit up Google to learn more. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The WrapPanel class can do that. [MSDN reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.wrappanel(v=vs.110).aspx)

Simply use it in XAML with

```
<WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
```

And add elements with

```
WrapPanel.Children.Add(UIElement);
```

in code behind.